# android SocialAuthError Could not connect using SocialAuth?

Tags: android, foursquare

i am using foursqure functionality in my application,one week ago my application was working with foursqure and i was getting sucessful login ,but now when i am using it again..,its giving me following error.

```
 "meta":{
"code":410,
"errorType":"param_error",
 "errorDetail":"The Foursquare API no longer supports requests that do not pass in a version    parameter. For more details see https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/overview\/versioning"
},
 "response":{
}
}
```

why i am getting this error.,it was working before few days but its not working now,i am unable to understand where i am doing wrong ,please help me for this,thankyou.

Comment: No i also faced the same .No response from foursqure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your request is probably **missing a parameter**.
Foursquare has changed it's api as of **January 28, 2014**.

*"Requests that do not include a v parameter will be rejected."*

You will need to add a `v` parameter which will be a date that represents the "version" of the API you expect from Foursquare.

```
v=YYYYMMDD
```

*Clients that wish to be robust against changes should always pass v=DATEVERIFIED (in the YYYYMMDD format) and watch for any deprecated responses coming back from the server.*

For more information visit:
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning

Comment: sir..,i applies that parameter but its not working..:(

Comment: @Asraf `v` value is a date in `YYYYMMDD` format. You send this date to verify that your software is handling Foursquare API up until that date. If they change anything on the API **after** that date, your app will still be able to use an earlier version of the API providing the date value as pointer to an earlier version of the API. For example: you build your app that works with current Foursquare API **today**. You put **v=20140212**. It will work. Foursquare changes the API a month later, you will be allright, because your date will point to an earlier API version, they used on 2014/02/12.

Comment: @Asraf benka is saying corretc

Comment: +1 I've scratching my head for 30 mins. You helped me!